# How to pass Model from View to PartialView in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a  View called `ShowAll` where I want to call another View `EmployeeRecord` and  `CustomerRecord`. It gives me error

> Message   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." string

near `@foreach (var item in Model){` in `EmployeeRecord` View.

I do not how it will hit the below `EmployeeRecord` Controller.

Can anyone please help me.

ClsShowAll model

```
  public class ClsShowAll
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClsEmployeeRecord> clsEmployeeRecord { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<ClsCustomerRecord> clsCustomerRecord { get; set; }  
    }
```

Controller

```
       public ActionResult ShowAll()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View "ShowAll"

```
        @model xx.xx.xx.ShowAll.ClsShowAll

             <div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default">                                           
                        <div class="panel-body">
                  @RenderPage("~/Views/EmployeeRecord/EmployeeRecord.cshtml")

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">                                            
                       <div class="panel-body"> 

                   @RenderPage("~/Views/CustomerRecord/CustomerRecord.cshtml")
                        </div>

                </div>

          </div>
```

EmployeeRecord View

```
        @model IEnumerable<xx.xx.xx.EmployeeRecord.ClsEmployeeRecord>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
                        </th>

                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult EmployeeRecord()
        {
           return View(Details.EmployeeList());
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us all three Views?

Comment: @Win, I have edited. Please see the changes and please help me here.

Comment: How ShowAll relate to EmployeeRecord in term of Model?

Comment: @Win, Sorry for late response. `EmployeeRecord` and `CustomerRecord` are Views. And your answer is related to partial view. In `ShowAll` view, I have pasted the whole code. I found ` @RenderPage("~/Views/EmployeeRecord/EmployeeRecord.cshtml")` code render the view inside view. I do not know, how to do this. I will add the `ShowAll` model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@Html.Partial(...)`.

If you want to pass a model to `PartialView`, then you can use           `@Html.Partial("EmployeeRecord", model.Employee)`

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
         @Html.Partial("EmployeeRecord")
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body"> 
         @Html.Partial("CustomerRecord")
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can download the sample source code of Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book by Adam Freeman, and see how `PartialView` work in -

- [List.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-mvc-5/blob/master/Chapter%2009/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/Views/Product/List.cshtml#L9)
- [ProductSummary.cshtml (ParitalView)](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-mvc-5/blob/master/Chapter%2009/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/Views/Shared/ProductSummary.cshtml)

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem.